# Use string created in a for statement outside it - Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop

If I have this piece of code:

```
for a in cookies {
    let b = "hello"
}

print (b) // This doesn't work
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: `let b = String() for a in cookies {
    b = "hello"
}  print (b)`

Comment: This does not work because variable b is a local variable in for loop which is not recognized outside of the loop. @ei-captain-v2-0 solution works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for a in cookies {
    let b = "hello"
}
```

`b` is declared inside of the for-loop's scope.
Therefore you will not have access to it when the loop ends.

Change your code to this

```
var b = ""
for a in cookies {
    b = "hello"
}
```

`b` is now declared out side of the for-loop's scope. Therefore you will have access to it after the loop completes.

Comment: To be picky, note that `b` in the second snippet is not only declared but also _instantiated_ outside of the `for`-loop's scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to [the accepted answer by @JTAppleCalendarforiOSSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42452881/4573247) that you may actually *declare* a local property without instantiating it if this is done directly prior to entering a scope which instantiates it (prior to first use of it).

```
let cookies = [1, 2]

var b: String // only declared, but not instantiated!
for a in cookies {
    b = "hello" // on first pass: instantiated
}
```

In the loop example above, this just seems weird, but it can be useful to avoid an extra unnecessary instantiation in case you know that instantiated value *will* be overwritten and never used; in which case you could let `b` be an immutable which is conditionally instantiated to different values depending on scope context. E.g.:

```
let foo = true // or 'false'

let b: String  // only declared
if foo {       // conditionally instantiated to "foo"
    b = "foo"
}
else {         // or, conditionally instantiated to "bar"
    b = "bar"
}

// 'b' has been instantiated to "foo" or "bar"
print(b) // "foo", for this example
```